# How Do I debug in server side code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have download & install vscode on my ubuntu 14.04 lts box, and It's working fine. I have created one app in node.js, and want to debug it. When I put debug point in my app.js file, and hit f5 (run), and seems it's working. But How to debug server side and client side code? Do you have any video tutorial in detail, so new user can understand it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

VSCode only supports node and mono (on linux and mac) debugging atm.
Client side debugging is not currently supported, you can vote for it here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code?filter=hot&page=1

We might produce video tutorials for new users soon.

In the meantime you can look at the docs
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/debugging

Answer (score 0):

The VSCode debugger does not support to debug clients (browsers) because browsers already have built-in debuggers (and other dev tools) that are much better integrated than VSCode can ever be.
So please use VSCode for debugging your node server and for debugging the client at the same time open the development tools of your browser.

Comment: It does now, you can attach/launch the process.